# @Value annotation is only loading default - not using property file

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file, spring-profiles

### Problem

I think that I havn't understood something properly because my @Value is always loading the default calue.

**Java Code**

So I have the following:

```
@Value("${disableQuerySecurityDebug:false}")
private boolean disableQuerySecurityDebug;
```

And this is set to false always.

**Property file:** **application-disableQuerySecurityDebug.properties**

I have a properties file called `application-disableQuerySecurityDebug.properties`.

And I have the following entry inside the file:

```
disableQuerySecurityDebugMne=true
```

And I run the application with the following profile: `disableQuerySecurityDebugMne`

I was expecting the value to be set to true, but it is always false.

### Update

Based on deadpool's answer, I ended up with the following:

```
    @Profile("disableQuerySecurityDebug") @Data
    @Configuration
    public class DisableSecurityConfig implements DisableQuerySecurityDebug {

        @Value("${disableQuerySecurityDebug:true}")
        private boolean securityDisabled;
    }

    @Profile("!disableQuerySecurityDebug") @Data
    @Configuration
    public class EnableSecurityConfig implements DisableQuerySecurityDebug{

        @Value("${disableQuerySecurityDebug:false}")
        private boolean securityDisabled;
    }

    public interface DisableQuerySecurityDebug{
        public boolean isSecurityDisabled();
    }
```

Comment: It should be the other way around, run with profile `disableQuerySecurityDebug` (based on the properties file name) and the property should be with `@Value("${disableQuerySecurityDebugMne:false}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Value` annotation is only used to inject properties values into spring Beans from `yml` or `properties` file

> This annotation can be used for injecting values into fields in Spring-managed beans and it can be applied at the field or constructor/method parameter level.

If you want to inject values based on profile specific then use `@Profile` on class

```
@Profile("disableQuerySecurityDebug")
@Configuration
public class Config {

 @Value("${disableQuerySecurityDebug:false}")
 private boolean disableQuerySecurityDebug;

  }
```

You could also specify it on the command line by using the following switch:

```
 java -jar demo.jar  --spring.profiles.active=disableQuerySecurityDebug
```

Comment: It would have been nice to have a simpler way. See my update.. I ended up needing to add a bit more code.